# Using AppleScript in Automator for replacing characters

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to create service in Apple Automator to replace the characters to another ones. For instance, if I want to transform a phone number format:

+X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX => XXXXXXXXXX

Thanks.

Comment: What, exactly, is the question? What you posted is a general statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Simple applescript code you can put in automator and it returns the output as a complete number = XXXXXXXXXX

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set inputNumber to input as text
    set outputNumber to ""
    if inputNumber begins with "+" then
        -- The Number begins with a + so convert number
        set noParts to the number of words of inputNumber
        repeat with cPart from 3 to noParts
            set outputNumber to outputNumber & word cPart of inputNumber
        end repeat
    end if
    return outputNumber
end run
```

Hope this helps!